# How to get remote debugging work for Java on Solaris

Tags: java, solaris, remote-debugging

I am trying to get remote debugging working with Java on Solaris OS. Following is what I have tried-

I have a Java class called TestP which has the main method.

When I try
java -classpath . TestP

the program works fine. But when I try adding the debug parameters to the JVM-

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n -classpath . TestP

It fails giving this error-

UTF ERROR ["../../../src/solaris/npt/utf_md.c":49]: Failed to complete iconv_open() setup

Can anyone please help me on figuring out why this error is coming up?? The above works fine on my Linux box.

Java version on Solaris:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.1-b02, mixed mode)

Java version on Linux:
java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.5) (fedora-20.b16.fc10-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 14.0-b15, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... This seems to be a known Solaris (not specific to Solaris 10) issue with Java 6, not a Java issue (see this [thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5184840)).

Someone has successfully applied a workaround (see this [blog post](http://timezra.blogspot.com/2007/12/nexenta-alpha-7-and-eclipse-debugger.html)) from a Sun guy, Jeff Moguillansky, but I wouldn't recommend it and rather consider searching sunsolve for a patch as indicated on Sun's forums.

Look at this one: http://sunsolve.sun.com/search/document.do?assetkey=1-1-6586755-1 (you'll need a Sun Online Account with a valid Support Contract or Software Subscription).

Comment: Thanks for the links. Will try to solve this problem with this information.

Comment: oracle broke all the links for this answer

Answer (score 2):

Using truss I found out that the process was looking for /usr/lib/iconv/geniconvtbl/binarytables/UTF-8%646.bt and 646%UTF-8.bt, so I just copied ISO8859-1%ISO646.bt to UTF-8%646.bt and ISO646%ISO8859-1.bt to 646%UTF-8.bt (yes, it is "646", not "ISO646"!)

This is of course a very ugly workaround and I have no idea if it has any negative effects on the JVM, but at least it starts the JVM without aborting. (I did this on OpenSolaris 2009.06, btw)

Answer (score 0):

If Pascal Thivent is right, then you may want to try running OpenSolaris (either on a blank machine or in a vm) and see if the problem is also there.  If not, then consider using that version for now if possible.